# Watch program settings during debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, application-settings

I have got a program where something is odd with the program settings which are edited at runtime. (I do save them, that's not the problem).

To find out about the problem, I want to do the stepwise debugging that VS offers. During that, I'd like to watch the settings as I can watch the variables.

Is that possible? How can I do that?

Comment: [Watch Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290869(v=vs.71).aspx)? At runtime you can right click a variable and add it to the watch window. it will keep track of the variable and show its value so long as it is within the scope of where you are currently debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could use the watch window or the Immediate window:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290869(v=vs.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy(v=vs.110).aspx

[image]

Immediate window executes C# code on the fly, watch windows shows the value of objects or variables. The windows will only be shown during runtime.